# Cannot read property makeUnauthenticatedRequest of undefined

Tags: amazon-web-services, ionic-framework, amazon-cognito

Following [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41797511/7135941) answer and still trying to implement a forgot password option, I tried doing it.

```
let cognitoUser = new AWSCognito.CognitoIdentityServiceProvider.CognitoUser({
  'Username': username,
  'Pool': aws_user_pools_id
});
cognitoUser.forgotPassword(...
```

However, I was immediately struck with this error:

```
Cannot read property 'makeUnauthenticatedRequest' of undefined
```

`makeUnauthenticatedRequest` is called inside an AWSCognito function (which I don't really have access to).

```
forgotPassword(callback) {
  this.client.makeUnauthenticatedRequest('forgotPassword' ...
```

I guess I'm missing something so that AWS could set up `this.client` but I do give him the correct ids ..?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found out the problem was coming from

```
    let cognitoUser = new AWSCognito.CognitoIdentityServiceProvider.CognitoUser({
      'Username': username,
      'Pool': aws_user_pools_id //HERE
   });
```

I assumed 'Pool' was the Cognito Pool id (a `string`), when it is a `CognitoUserPool` object.

What I had to do was to create the CognitoUserPool Object:

```
  getUserPool() {
    return new AWSCognito.CognitoIdentityServiceProvider.CognitoUserPool({
      "UserPoolId": aws_user_pools_id,
      "ClientId": aws_user_pools_web_client_id
    });
  }
```

Then create the CognitoUser with this CognitoUserPool object

```
reset_password(username) {
  let cognitoUser = new AWSCognito.CognitoIdentityServiceProvider.CognitoUser({
    'Username': username,
    'Pool': this.getUserPool()
  });
  ...
}
```